# State Returning Undefined --React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to fetch value from Async Storage and assign it to State. 
Value of state is coming null/undefined while accessing inculcating to URL

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stAccntList: [],
        stUserAccountNo: '',
        stCustNo: '',
        resp: '',
    };
    AsyncStorage.getItem('UserAccountNo').then((value) => {
        if (value != '') {
            accno = value;
            this.setState({ stUserAccountNo: value });
           // alert(this.state.stUserAccountNo);
        }
    }).done();
    AsyncStorage.getItem('CustomerNo').then((value) => {

        if (value != '') {
            cusno = value;
            this.setState({ stCustNo: value });
           // alert(this.state.stUserAccountNo);

        }
    }).done();


}


     componentWillMount() {

        let restUrl = urls.URL + this.state.stCustNo + "/" + "accounts" + "/" + this.state.stUserAccountNo;

}
```

this.state.CustNo and this.state.stUserAccountNo  is returning null .

Please let me know where its going wrong.

Comment: Since you are trying to fetch data asynchronously and updating state, its not guranteed that the data is available before the componentWillMount is executed.

Comment: how to achieve that?

Comment: Depends on what the purpose of restUrl is in componentWillMount

Comment: I will Hit API with that restUrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to fetch data asynchronously and updating state, its not guranteed that the data is available before the componentWillMount is executed.

You could make use of `async-await` in componentDidMount instead

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stAccntList: [],
        stUserAccountNo: '',
        stCustNo: '',
        resp: '',
    };

}

async componentDidMount() {
   var userAccountNo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserAccountNo');
   var CustomerNo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('CustomerNo');
   if (userAccountNo != '') {
        this.setState({ stUserAccountNo: userAccountNo });
   }
   if (CustomerNo != '') {
        this.setState({ stCustNo: CustomerNo });
   }
   if(userAccountNo !== '' && CustomerNo !== '') {
     var restUrl = urls.URL + this.state.stCustNo + "/" + "accounts" + "/" + this.state.stUserAccountNo;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `restURL` used right away or at a later time (ie. click event or some other event later)? If it is used right away, you will likely want to use [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) or [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to track when both `AsyncStorage` have completed before using restURL. If you are using the URL at a later time, then you could simply rely on it completing before you need to use it or check right before use.

Comment: I will use right away below restUrl in componentWillMount

Comment: Then look into promises and async await. You have to know that both AsyncStorages have completed (triggered their `then()`) to know you have the data back.